# Get number equation using specific set of values for get given answer

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have do it for AI assignment. Need a logic for finding solution ..Here is the explanation of problem .

I have answer ( any number like for example 10 ). And have some set of numbers (like for example [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]). Now I have to create equation using ( + , - , * , / ) and numbers to get the answer 10.

This is first step ( not fix length or condition for repeating numbers ).. there are many solution for this like

5 + 5 = 10 ( 2 step ) 2 * 2 = 10 ( 2 step )

2 * 2 + 6 = 10 ( 3 step ) 3 * 2 + 4 = 10 ( 3 step ) ...and on

On second step (more difficult )( next assignment after this ) is Have to set some conditions like --> must be in specific step ...Or --> must don't repeater number twice ( if in array here two times 5 than we can use it two times ) --> must have to use * twice

I am not too expert in AI But any helpful link will also welcome Thanks in Advance

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What is your question?